# Why h:dataTable in Java Server Faces doesn't render h:inputText in the table rows

Tags: java, rest, jsf-2.2

I am a newbie to Java EE and JSF and I spent days on this issue without reaching any conclusion. Now I am hoping someone can give me a guidance.I have searched this forum on this problem, found some useful answers but nothing that could solve my problem.

I have a JSF page showing "parts" (part name, part number, part description, etc.) in a tabulated from using the h:dataTable tag. The rows all have update and delete links. When I click on the link for "update" for a given row, the boolean flag never toggles from 'false' to 'true' so for the h:inputText to render in the row, where I can update the part information. I see through the logs that flag is toggle from 'false' to 'true' but when the control returns from the bean to the JSF page, somehow (mysteriously) the flag toggles back to 'false', therefore, the associated h:inputText for update does not render and I cannot update the part information in that row.
The JSF page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <title>This is a part number list service</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css"  />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h2> You are authorized to use the Part number List Service</h2>
            <p style="text-align: center">
                <h:dataTable value ="#{partList.parts}" var="p"
                             styleClass="part-table"
                             headerClass="part-table-header"
                             rowClasses="part-table-odd-row,part-table-even-row"
                             border="10"
                             >
                    <f:facet name="caption">
                        <h3> <h:outputText value="#{bundle.caption}" /> </h3>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p></p>    
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Part Name</f:facet>
                            #{p.name}
                        <h:inputText value = "#{p.name}"
                                     size = "5" rendered = "#{p.canUpdate}" />
                        <h:outputText value = "#{p.name}"
                                      rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Part Manufacture</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value = "#{p.manufacture}"
                                     size = "10" rendered = "#{p.canUpdate}" />
                        <h:outputText value = "#{p.manufacture}"
                                      rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Part Number</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value = "#{p.number}"
                                     size = "15" rendered = "#{p.canUpdate}" />
                        <h:outputText value = "#{p.number}"
                                      rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Part Description</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value = "#{p.description}"
                                     size = "10" rendered = "#{p.canUpdate}" />
                        <h:outputText value = "#{p.description}"
                                      rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value = "#{p.price}"
                                     size = "5" rendered = "#{p.canUpdate}" />
                        <h:outputText value = "#{p.price}"
                                      rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name = "header">Update</f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value = "Update" 
                                       action = "#{partList.updateLinkAction(p)}" 
                                       rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}">
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name = "header">Delete</f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value = "Delete" 
                                       action = "#{partList.deleteAction(p)}" 
                                       rendered = "#{not p.canUpdate}">
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </p>
                <p></p>
                <h:commandButton id="back"
                                 value="Logout"
                                 action="auth" />
                <h:commandButton id="update"
                                 value="Save updates"
                                 action="#{partList.saveUpdate}" />
                

            <h2> Add new part</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Part Name</td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="addpartname" size="10" value="#{partList.partName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Part Manufacture</td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="addpartmanufacture" size="10" value="#{partList.partManufacture}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Part Number</td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="addpartnumbere" size="10" value="#{partList.partNumber}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Part Description</td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="addpartdescription" size="10" value="#{partList.partDescription}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$Price</td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="addpartprice" size="10" value="#{partList.partPrice}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p></p>
            <h:commandButton id="addparttolist" 
                             value="Add part"
                             action="#{partList.addAction}" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the managed bean that is annotated with @SessionScope

```
@FacesConfig
@Named
@SessionScoped

public class PartList implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    RequestSessionBean request;

    private List<Part> parts;
    private String partName;
    private String partNumber;
    private String partManufacture;
    private String partDescription;
    private float price;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerUtil.getLogger(PartList.class.getName(),
            "C:\\Logs\\log.txt");

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1000L;

    private void update(Part p) {
        logger.entering(PartList.class.getName(), "update");

        if (p.getCanUpdate()) {
            try {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "NB: Updating part. Part number:{0} Part name: {1} can update: {2}",
                        new Object[]{p.getNumber(), p.getName(), p.getCanUpdate()});
                request.removePart(p.getId());
                request.addPart(p);
                parts = request.getAllParts();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "NB: something went wrong", e);
                throw (new EJBException(e));
            }
            logger.exiting(PartList.class.getName(), "NB: leaving update()");
        }
    }

    public PartList() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "NB PartList default constructor called");
    }

    public void setPartName(String n) {
        partName = n;
    }

    public String getPartName() {
        return partName;
    }

    public void setPartNumber(String n) {
        partNumber = n;
    }

    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public String getPartManufacture() {
        return partManufacture;
    }

    public void setPartManufacture(String n) {
        partManufacture = n;
    }

    public void setPartDescription(String p) {
        partDescription = p;
    }

    public String getPartDescription() {
        return partDescription;
    }

    public void setPartPrice(float p) {
        price = p;
    }

    public float getPartPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public List getParts() {
        try {
            parts = request.getAllParts();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return parts;
    }

    public String deleteAction(Part p) {
        request.removePart(p.getId());
        parts = request.getAllParts();
        return null;
    }

    public String addAction() {
        Part p = new Part(partName, partManufacture, partNumber, partDescription, price);
        request.addPart(p);
        parts = request.getAllParts();
        clearDataField(); //clear the form data after add operation
        return null;
    }

    private void clearDataField() {
        this.partDescription = null;
        this.partManufacture = null;
        this.partName = null;
        this.partNumber = null;
        this.price = 0;
    }

    public String updateLinkAction(Part p) { //update link clicked
        logger.entering(PartList.class.getName(), "updateLinkAction");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "NB: Updating part. Part number:{0} Part name: {1} can update: {2}",
                new Object[]{p.getNumber(), p.getName(), p.getCanUpdate()});
        p.setCanUpdate(true);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Can update is now :{0}",
                p.getCanUpdate());
        logger.exiting(PartList.class.getName(), "updateLinkAction");
        return null; //This allows the page flow remain on the same page
    }

    public String saveUpdate() {
        parts.stream()
                .forEach(e -> e.setCanUpdate(false));
        parts.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getCanUpdate())
                .forEach(e -> update(e));

        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is a singleton session bean that is used to initially populate the table in the database from an XML file using JAXB.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
//This bean will be managed by the container automatically since it is a singleton. The container calls 
//the method that has a @PostConstruct annotation. This is ideal to perform initial data load into the
// the data store
public class DataLoaderSessionBean {
    @EJB
    private RequestSessionBean request;
    private final static String logPath="C:\\Logs\\log.txt";
    private final static String dataPath="c:\\Logs\\Parts.xml";
    private final static Logger logger=LoggerUtil.getLogger(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(), logPath);
    private void saveData(){
        logger.entering(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(),"saveData()");
         try {
            List<Part> parts = request.getAllParts();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(PartWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            // Wrapping our person data.
            PartWrapper wrapper = new PartWrapper();
            wrapper.setParts(parts);

            // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
            m.marshal(wrapper, new File(dataPath));
            m.marshal(parts, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.exiting(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(),"saveData()");
    }
     private List<Part> loadData(){
        logger.entering(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(),"loadData()");
         List<Part> parts=null;
         try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(PartWrapper.class);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
            PartWrapper wrapper = (PartWrapper) um.unmarshal(new File(dataPath));
            parts = wrapper.getParts();

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.exiting(DataLoaderSessionBean.class.getName(),"loadData()");
        return parts;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void createData(){
        request.addParts(loadData());
    }
    
     @PreDestroy
    public void deleteData() {
        saveData();
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Entity bean for the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_PART")
@NamedQuery(
        name = "findAllParts",
        query = "SELECT p FROM Part p "
        + "ORDER BY p.number"
)
@SessionScoped

public class Part implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1001L;
    private static final String logPath="C:\\Logs\\log.txt";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerUtil.getLogger(Part.class.getName()
             ,logPath);
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String manufacture;
    @NotNull
    private String number;
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private float price;
    //@Transient
    // @XmlTransient
    private boolean canUpdate;

    public Part() {

    }

    public Part(String n, String m, String nu, String d, float p) {
        name = n;
        manufacture = m;
        number = nu;
        description = d;
        price = p;
    }

    public void setId(Long l) {
        id = l;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNumber(String n) {
        number = n;
    }

    //  @Id
    //  @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setManufacture(String n) {
        manufacture = n;
    }

    public String getManufacture() {
        return manufacture;
    }

    public void setDescription(String d) {
        description = d;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPrice(float p) {
        price = p;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setCanUpdate(boolean b) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "NB: Part.setCanUpdate() for part name {0} with id {1} and canUpdate {2}",
                 new Object[]{this.name, this.id, b});
        canUpdate = b;
    }

    public boolean getCanUpdate() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "NB: Part.getCanUpdate() for Part name {0} with id {1} and CanUpate {2}",
                 new Object[]{this.name, this.id, this.canUpdate});
        return canUpdate;
    }
}
```

Here is the session bean that interacts with the database.

```
@Stateful
public class RequestSessionBean {

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public void createPart(String name,
            String manufacture,
            String partNumber,
            String description,
            float price) {
        try {
            Part part = new Part(name,
                    manufacture,
                    partNumber,
                    description,
                    price);
            em.persist(part);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new EJBException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void addParts(List<Part> parts){
        parts.stream()
                .forEach(e->addPart(e));
    }
    public void addPart(Part p){
        try {
            em.persist(p);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new EJBException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public List<Part> getAllParts() {
        List<Part> parts = (List<Part>) em.createNamedQuery("findAllParts").getResultList();
        return parts;
    }
    public Part getPart(String partNumber){
        Part p=null;
        try {
            p  = em.find(Part.class, partNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EJBException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return p;
    }
    public void removePart(Long id) {
        try {
            Part p = em.find(Part.class, id);
            em.remove(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EJBException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a data wrapper for the JAXB marshalling/unmarshalling

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PartWrapper")
public class PartWrapper {
    List<Part> parts;
    public List<Part> getParts(){
        return parts;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="part")
    public void setParts(List<Part> p){
        parts=p;
    }
    public void add(Part p){
        if(parts==null){
            parts = new ArrayList();
        }
        parts.add(p);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple utility class for logging

```
public class LoggerUtil {

    public static Logger getLogger(String className, String pathToLogFile) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
        for (Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
            logger.removeHandler(h);
        }
            logger.addHandler(getFileHandler(pathToLogFile));
            logger.addHandler(getConsoleHandler());
            logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);

        return logger;
    }
    private static Handler getConsoleHandler(){
         ConsoleHandler handle = new ConsoleHandler();
        handle.setLevel(Level.FINER);
        handle.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        return handle;
    }
    private static Handler getFileHandler(String pathToLogFile){
        Handler handle=null;
        try {
            handle = new FileHandler(pathToLogFile,10240,1, true);
            handle.setLevel(Level.FINER);
            handle.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

        } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
        }
        return handle;
    }
}
```

Here is the initial data load for the database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PartWrapper>
    <part>
        <canUpdate>false</canUpdate>
        <description>EGR Valve</description>
        <id>7</id>
        <manufacture>Emission Systems</manufacture>
        <name>EGR Valve</name>
        <number>EV4301766ES</number>
        <price>29.95</price>
    </part>
    <part>
        <canUpdate>false</canUpdate>
        <description>Carborator float</description>
        <id>6</id>
        <manufacture>Duke Carboration</manufacture>
        <name>Floater Element</name>
        <number>FE3511029DC</number>
        <price>3.99</price>
    </part>
</PartWrapper>
```

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>showpartnumer.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have two other versions of this application: One version uses an XML file as the datastore. Another version uses a Java Collection to keep the data in memory. They both work fine, however, once I created this version to use the database this problem with updating rows immerged.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I looked into your code and it seems like an environment setup. I was able to update a part by clicking on the update link. Currently, your code has many pitfalls that might lead to errors preventing the container from rendering your application. You need to make sure to catch and log exceptions in your singleton. They are container-managed and they should not throw exceptions. In addition, before adding rows to the database, ensure the row does not exist. For instance, when you shut down the Glassfish server, it does not automatically shut down the DB servers, so upon server re-start, your tables from the previous run still in the database, and your code will try to load the rows once again from an XML file, which will lead to duplicate key exceptions; hence the Singleton let these exceptions to bubble up to the container level and your application will never start.

In addition, during the testing phase, when you manually adding data into DB from an XML file, it would be better to have the application to generate the PK for the entities to eschew duplicate primary key errors. For instance, when using Netbeans IDE in concert with Apache Derby, every time the DB server is recycled the pk generation starts from a set initial value after the application is up and running. In your case, say you loaded a row from an XML with PK=1, then on your next add from the application's JSF page, there will be a PK conflict with this existing row.

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to update after playing fair amount of time with the environment. Thanks for all the suggestion, now I know why I am getting all those duplicate primary key exception. I marked your response as the answer.